# validation errors when validating a page that has a flash object

Tags: html, flash, xhtml

I use the following doctype in a page that has a flash object,

html code

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="379" height="180">
<param name="movie" value="Flash/header.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<embed src="Flash/header.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="379" height="180"></embed>
</object>
```

When I try to validate the page Im displayed with the following errors,

```
there is no attribute "src"
there is no attribute "quality"
there is no attribute "pluginspage"
there is no attribute "type" 
there is no attribute "width"  
there is no attribute "height" 
there is no attribute "type"
```

Could some one please advice me with some information on how to embed a flash object[.swf] in a page with no validation errors?

Comment: try embedding with swfobject(http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/), samples included in the zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`embed` is a old element invented by Netscape and never was standardized. Search google for dozens of valid ways to embed flash: http://www.google.de/search?q=embed+flash+valid

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will work.

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Flash/header.swf" width="379" height="180">
<!-- <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="379" height="180">
    <param name="movie" value="Flash/header.swf" />
<!-->
  </object>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```